# Does register my custom cluster selection strategy need to compile source code?

Tags: orientdb

I see the doc2.1.x describe the custom cluster selection strategy as follows:
that Register the implementation as a service.  You can do this by creating a new file under `META-INF/service`.  Use the filename `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.clusterselection.OClusterSelectionStrategy`.  For its contents, code your class with the full package.

Does it mean I must modify source code project, compile and publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must modify the source code project and compile.
I have followed the docs http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Cluster-Selection.html#custom-cluster-selection-strategies
and it works.

[image]